# How to generate SQL data based on existing tables?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql

Recently I had to create database with around 300,000 rows in order to do some basic testing. I had to "manually" create tables Customer, Product and Supplier - they contain around 3,000 rows.

And now I'm stuck on filling Order and OrderItem tables correctly based on the data in those 3 tables.
So my question is, how can I generate over 200,000 rows in Order and OrderItem using only SQL queries and respecting constraints?
I know how to manually add (row by row) but that would take weeks. The worst thing is that I'm stuck on this for couple of days and can't move forward without it.

I'm genuinely sorry for asking this dummy question but I would really appericiate any help, thank you in advance!

This is E-R diagram of my database :

[image: E-R diagram]

Comment: Do you want random data?  Or something else?

Comment: If you want random data, a few simple queries will do the trick. Easy to produce a few million rows.

Comment: How are the Orders placed and where do you get the data for 200,000 records?

Comment: I just want random data, only those 3 mentioned tables needed to be created manually. Orders and OrderItems needs to be created completely randomly, it just needs to have correct IDs - it just needs to be correct, doesn't matter how. @Impaler

Comment: Yep, just random data (check my comment above) @wallyk

Comment: So, basically, if we add 2 rows in OrderItems :
`code`
INSERT INTO [OrderItem] ([Id],[OrderId],[ProductId],[UnitPrice],[Quantity])VALUES(1,1,11,14.00,12)
 INSERT INTO [OrderItem] ([Id],[OrderId],[ProductId],[UnitPrice],[Quantity])VALUES(2,1,42,9.80,10)
`code`

And since those two rows have the same OrderId they should be put in only one row in the Orders table. So no matter how many items were ordered, if it has same OrderId it should be put in one row.
I just don't know how to create that, how to create that query - how to connect it. @paone

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the customer & products table contains items.

You can try somehting like this:

```
-- Generage 1 year of dates
DECLARE @StartDate  date = '2020-01-01';
DECLARE @CutoffDate date = DATEADD(DAY, -1, DATEADD(YEAR, 1, @StartDate));
        
;WITH seq(n) AS 
(
    SELECT 0 UNION ALL SELECT n + 1 FROM seq
    WHERE n < DATEDIFF(DAY, @StartDate, @CutoffDate)
)
SELECT DATEADD(Day,n, GetDate()) Date 
INTO #Dates
FROM seq
ORDER BY n 
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0);
        
-- Generates an Order for each customer for each date
INSERT INTO [Order](CustomerId, OrderDate, OrderNumber)
SELECT c.Id
    , d.Date
    , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY NewId())
FROM Customer c
-- Using join to filter out data, random customer on random date.
INNER JOIN #Dates d on abs(checksum(c.Id) % 2) = abs(checksum(d.Date) % 2)
        
-- Generate order items, for each order add 3 products with random price / quantity
INSERT INTO OrderItem(OrderId, ProductId, UnitPrice, Quantity)
SELECT x.OrderId, x.ProductId
—- , abs(checksum(NewId()) % 100) + 1 -- Random price between 1 and 100
, x.UnitPrice
,  abs(checksum(NewId()) % 10) + 1 -- Random quantity between 1 and 10
FROM (
    SELECT o.Id OrderId, p.Id ProductId,p.UnitPrice ROW_NUMBER() oVER (PARTITION BY o.Id ORDER BY NewId()) n
    FROM [Order] o, Product P
) x
WHERE x.N <= 3 -- Max 3 products per order
```

you can run the bottom query multiple times, to add more order items to an order. (possibility to add duplicate products with different prices)

Comment: Thank you, I really appericiate the help, I've successfully generated more than 300k rows of Orders, but can you just guide me on how to change one small thing in your bottom query : How can I get the real price of the products based on their ID and not just the random value? Thank you in advance once again, you've helped me a lot. @Preben

Comment: You can select p.UnitPrice in the subquery instead of the random price

Comment: One big thank you once again, I've managed to get 10x times more data with your code, I just struggle to get that real product value (based on ProductId) instead of random values because I'm a dumdum and new to SQL. By the way, leave me your PayPal link so I can buy you a coffee at least :) @Preben

Comment: Holy sh*t man, thank you so much, I appericate your help a lot, I wish you all the best @Preben

Answer (score 0):

You can generate random data by using ROW_NUMBER() randomly and then JOINING based on row_number(). We are generating random quantity using [RAND()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/rand-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) function

```sql
;WITH CTE_RandomProduct as
(
SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY NEWID()) as rnk
from Product
),
CTE_RandomOrder as
(
SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY NEWID()) as rnk
from Order
)
INSERT INTO [OrderItem] ([OrderId],[ProductId],[UnitPrice],[Quantity])
SELECT o.orderId, p.productid,p.unitprice,cast((RAND(o.orderId)  * 100 ) as int) as quantity
from CTE_RandomProduct as p
INNER JOIN CTE_RandomOrder as o
on p.rnk = o.rnk
WHERE o.rnk < 10000 -- to restrict the number of rows
```